# Can a MySQL query using a BETWEEN clause take columns instead of values?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which stores dates as start_date and end_date. On submit of form, I want to check if there already exist a row in my table.

Is it possible to have a query like this:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE post_value BETWEEN start_date AND end_date;
```

Comment: If only there were a way to find out...

Comment: Sure it is possible so long as `post_value`, `start_date`, and `end_date` are in a format that follows your database engine's acceptable format.

Answer (score 1):

DATE_SUB and DATE_ADD are functions where you can define a date for example:

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name WHERE post_value BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 20 SECOND) AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 100 SECOND);
```

(NOW() can also be a column)